# How to refresh the parent page from the child one in server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, cross-browser

I open a new tab like this :

```
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("window.open('Signature.aspx','_blank')");
        Response.Write("</script>");
```

Now from the `Signature.aspx`

I want to refresh the parent page . How to do this ?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here as the parent window will have only just been rendered when the 2nd window is opened, so refreshing it will have no effect (and may open the new window again, infinitely).

Answer (score 0):

from the child:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

edit:

if you want it from codebehind...you need the child page to cause a postback via a button click or something...so in that you'd register the above line as a startup script

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "refresh", "window.opener.location.reload();", true);
```

Comment: A hint from experience - add a `;` to the end of ALL scripts you add to the page.  If you were to add another bit of script later they'd both fail without it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change `_Blank` to `_Top` and it should refresh the outtermost page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    Response.Write("<script>");
    Response.Write("window.open('Signature.aspx','_blank'); window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location;");
    Response.Write("</script>");
```